# canConstruct memoization giving wrong output

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was trying to memoize the canConstruct function, that takes target string and wordBank as inputs and this function checks if the given target string can be formed using the words given in the wordBank.
I wrote the following code:

```
def canConstruct(target, wordBank, memo={}):
    if target in memo:
        return memo[target]

    if target == "":
        return True
    for i in wordBank:
        if target.find(i) == 0:
            suffix = target[len(i):]
            if canConstruct(suffix, wordBank, memo) == True:
                memo[target] = True
                return True

    memo[target] = False
    return False


print(canConstruct("abcdef", ['ab', 'abc', 'cd', 'def', 'abcd']))
print(canConstruct("nandeesh", ['na', 'deesh', 'cd', 'n', 'abcd']))
print(canConstruct("skateboard", [
      'bo', 'rd', 'ate', 't', 'ska', 'sk', 'boar']))
print(canConstruct("enterapotentpot", [
      'a', 'p', 'ent', 'enter', 'ot',  'o', 't']))

print(canConstruct("eeef", ['ef', 'ee', 'eee', 'eeee', 'eeeee', 'eeeeee']))
```

From the code, it is clear that the last output should be `True` as the string `eeef` can be formed by using `ee` + `ef`. But, surprisingly, the function returns `False`. I have checked a few online compilers as well and all of them give `False` as the output. Only one actually returned `True`, i.e. [pythontutor.com](https://pythontutor.com/).

I am not sure why that is the case, or my memoized function is malfunctioning?
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: IDLE is giving `True`